# Error Instalando React en Windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, cmd, npm

Estoy intendado instalar react en mi pc con Windows.

Usando el siguiente comando:

```
C:\Users\Gonza\Desktop>npx create-react-app myapp
```

Estoy obteniendo el siguiente resultado de error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Found: @babel/core@7.12.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/core
npm ERR!   @babel/core@"7.12.3" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!     react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   @babel/core@"^7.12.3" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/@svgr/webpack
npm ERR!     @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!       react-scripts@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (babel-jest, babel-loader, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @babel/core@"^7.13.0" from @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@7.13.12
npm ERR! node_modules/@babel/preset-env/node_modules/@babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining
npm ERR!   @babel/plugin-bugfix-v8-spread-parameters-in-optional-chaining@"^7.13.12" from @babel/preset-env@7.13.12
npm ERR!   node_modules/@babel/preset-env
npm ERR!     @babel/preset-env@"^7.12.1" from @svgr/webpack@5.5.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/@svgr/webpack
npm ERR!       @svgr/webpack@"5.5.0" from react-scripts@4.0.3
npm ERR!       node_modules/react-scripts
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\Gonza\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gonza\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-04T04_51_28_779Z-debug.log

Aborting installation.
  npm install --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting myapp/ from C:\Users\Gonza\Desktop
Done.
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Gonza\Desktop
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c "create-react-app "myapp""

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gonza\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-04T04_51_28_892Z-debug.log
```

Estas son las versiones de las librerias que estoy usando:

version de npm: 7.0.8

version de node: 15.2.1

Alguien tiene una idea de a que se debe que este generandose?

Comment: Si tratas de correrlo de como `npx create-react-app myapp --legacy-peer-deps` ¿Qué sucede?

Comment: hola jose. ya he intentado hacer eso, tambien probe npx create-react-app myapp --force y arroja el mismo error

Comment: Prueba utilizando la ultima versión de npm y de node. Puede que así funcione

Comment: Hola lucas!! Efectivamente eso hice y fue la solución, muchas gracias a todos

Comment: Has un update a la ultima version de Npm y Node, seguramente es un conflicto que tienes versiones nuevas de otras librerras como Babel.